# Linked List to single list, iteratively

Tags: python

I need to turn link list into a single list, but I do not know how to do it iterativeley. An example is:

```
r = link(1, link('hello', link('world', empty)))
 copy_list_recursive(r)
 [1, 'hello', 'world']
```

my Starter codes are :

```
def is_link(s):
    """s is a linked list if it is empty or a (first, rest) pair."""
    return s == empty or (len(s) == 2 and is_link(s[1]))


def link(first, rest):
    """Construct a linked list from its first element and the rest."""
    assert is_link(rest), "rest must be a linked list."
    return [first, rest]

def first(s):
    """Return the first element of a linked list s."""
    assert is_link(s), "first only applies to linked lists."
    assert s != empty, "empty linked list has no first element."
    return s[0]


def rest(s):
    """Return the rest of the elements of a linked list s."""
    assert is_link(s), "rest only applies to linked lists."
    assert s != empty, "empty linked list has no rest."
    return s[1]
```

I solved the problem recursively, but do not know how to implement it iterative.
here is the code using recursion:

```
if lst is empty:
        return []
    else:
        return [first(lst) + copy_list_recursive(rest(lst))]
```

Comment: What is `copy_list_recursive` and `empty`?

Comment: copy_list_recursive is just the same defintion, i just changed the name to know it is a recursive function.  and empty = 'empty' since in linked stacks there are types called None type.

Comment: I  need to make another definition called copy_list_iteritivley, hence basically I'm doing the same problem but in a different method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iterative variant directly follows from the recursive—they're two sides of the same coin.

1. Extract the first item
2. Move onto the second

Repeat until you reach the end (i.e., `empty`). You will need a `while` loop. The stopping condition is `lst != empty`.

```
def copy_list_iterative(lst):
    data = []

    while lst != empty:
         data.append(lst[0])
         lst = lst[1]

    return data
```

```
>>> copy_list_iterative(link(1, link('hello', link('world', empty))))
[1, 'hello', 'world']
```

Comment: Thank you, and ya, I found the recursive way, but I just kept forgetting the to stop the condition on the while loop. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Errick-MichaelSantos And possibly share your homework credit with me, I could use some of it.

Comment: @Errick-MichaelSantos thanks, you can also upvote answers if you found them helpful--click the triangle above the 0.